# How do I change the selected rows of a DT::dataTable on server-side? How do make it jump to the correct view?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to output a dataTable and preselect a row. This row can have a higher number than 10, in which case I want it to be shown in the dataTable. I have read you could use a `dataTableProxy` but it does not jump to the correct row. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("dtout")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dtout<- DT::renderDT(iris)
  dtproxy<-DT::dataTableProxy(session = session,outputId = "dtout")
  DT::selectRows(dtproxy,14)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is the result:
[image: Table not at the correct position]

This is what I want to be shown directly:
[image: Table if it was correct]

Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the **Select** extension. But you have to know in advance the number of the page to be displayed (maybe there's a way to get it automatically, I don't know).

```r
library(DT)

callback <- "
table.row(':eq(13)', {page: 'all'}).select(); // select row 13+1
table.page(1).draw('page');                   // jump to page 1+1
"
datatable(
  iris,
  extensions = "Select", selection = "none",
  callback = JS(callback)
)
```

Comment: Inspired by your answer I tried out to put the line `DT::selectPage(dtproxy,2)` behind the `DT::selectRows(dtproxy,14)` in my own code but this had no effect. Can you explain that? Is the meaning of page what I think: One of these 15 buttons at the bottom of the table? Or is it something else?

Comment: @Noskario I also tried the same, no effect indeed.

Comment: Is that a bug? Nevermind. When I plot datatable, your code works, but when I want to deploy it in a Shiny-app, then the callbacks have no effect. What I did: `res<-datatable(iris, extensions = "Select", selection = "none",  callback = JS(callback))` and then `output$dtout <- DT::renderDT(res)`. I still get the wrong view and not even the row is marked...

Comment: @Noskario I think you have to use the `server=FALSE` option of `renderDT`.